# Find aggregation on arbitrary number of different keys

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in mongoDB which looks like,

```
 collection:

   doc1
    { field1 : {
            field1_1 : 'val1',
            field1_2 : 'val2',
            field1_3 : 'val3',
            ...
            field1_N : 'valN' } }

   doc2
    { field1 : {
            field1_1 : 'val1',
            field1_2 : 'val2',
            field1_3 : 'val3',
            ...
            field1_N : 'valN' } }
```

I want to find aggregation(sum, avg, min, max) on `val1, val2, val3 ... valN`. Is there any way to use mongo's aggregation feature? The keys are always different, and the aggregation should happen for all the values of `field1`

**Edited:**

The final output should look like,

```
   doc1
    { field1 : {
            sum: sumOf(val1, val2... valN),
            avg: avgOf(val1, val2... valN)
            ... } }

   doc2
    { field1 : {
            sum: sumOf(val1, val2... valN),
            avg: avgOf(val1, val2... valN)
            ... } }
```

Comment: Only one solution [`MapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/)

Comment: I have to use only `aggregation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a mongodb ninja by any means, but I've a solution for your question. It's not the most efficient one, but if you are royally stuck, you can use it.

So the code below, creates a projection, of the avg data of the fields that you want to aggregate (avg) on, the down side to this is that you have to specify each field, rather than maybe a way of iterating through all fields and aggregating on that. You can definitely do iterations using JS, I've briefly come across it in the past, but it might take a small bit more tweaking than the code I've provided below.

Also, I've assumed that, field1.field1_1 : "int". Is an integer and not a string value.

```
db.random.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project:
            {
                _id: "$field1",
                avgAmount: { $avg: ["$field1.field1_1", "$field1.field1_2", "$field1.field1.3"]}
            }
        }]
)
```

Best of luck anyway #1love.

Comment: That's also a way. But what if we don't know what are all the fields available now? sometimes field1_1 present and sometimes not. The same for all. So, it should be generic not specific.

Comment: If it doesn't exist, it will just skip it for example if you add in the above query "$field1.field1.4" and there is no value to it, it will just be omitted. There is an argument that the dataset could be restructured. For example  create an array, field1 [{name: field1_1}, {value: x}. Then it's much easier to aggregate on the value field, than the way you have it atm.

Answer (score 1):

can try this one using [Map-Reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/) instead of aggregate for your requirement. map-reduce operations provide some flexibility that is not presently available in the aggregation pipeline.

```
var mapFunction = 
  function() {
    for (key in this.field1) {
      emit(this._id, parseInt(this.field1[key]));
    }
  };

  var reduceFunction = 
  function(key, values) {
    return {sum:Array.sum(values), avg:Array.avg(values)};
  };

db.getCollection('collectionName').mapReduce(mapFunction, reduceFunction, {out: {inline:1}});
```

As far I know if your document structure would be like :

```
field1 : [
            {field1 : 'val1'},
            {field1 : 'val2'},
            {field1 : 'val3'},
            ...
            {field1 : 'valN'}]
```

then you could solved easily by using `aggregate`. so for your structure `mapReducemay` better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try $sum for sum and $multiply for multiplication.. you can find all the aggregate functions available for MongoDb at the following link:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/

hope this helps..